# C# loop over List<T> collection and find if value exists is saying projectname

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

I want to see if a value exist in a Collection of properties that I have.
Performance is not important.

```
 //Insert all the main without wav match 
foreach(var mainOnly in fileStuff)
{
    var finalCollection = new FinalFile();

    var result = finalFile.First(s => s.MainId == mainOnly.ParsedName);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        finalCollection.ClientName = mainOnly.ClientName;
        finalCollection.MainId = mainOnly.ParsedName;
        //finalCollection.WavName = Convert.ToInt64(wav.ParsedName);
        finalCollection.LastWriteTime = mainOnly.CreationTime;
        finalCollection.folder = mainOnly.FolderName;
        mainAll.Add(finalCollection);
    }         
}
```

I'm looping over a 1,000 records and I don't want to add in another loop, so I figured I would

1. check to see if  `s.MainId == mainOnly.ParsedName`    e.g.  34343  == 23445
2. if ( nothing returns )  then add to my new collection

**Problem**

```
// what am i doing wrong here?  It is not right 
var result = finalFile.First(s => s.MainId == mainOnly.ParsedName);

// this is not right as it won't compile as "result" = 'ConAppFolderFileFinder.FinalFile'
// that is my projectname.FinalFile   :/
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
```

Comment: You should use `FirstOrDefault()`, which will return `null` if there is no item that matches your condition. `First()` will throw an exception if no item is returned.

Comment: use FirstOrDefault(...) and check if result is null

Comment: Both `First` and `FirstOrDefault` won´t help OP as they return an instance of `FileName` instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you will just check if your query even returns *any* element, so you can use this approach:

```
if(finalFile.Any(s => s.MainId == mainOnly.ParsedName))
{
    finalCollection.ClientName = mainOnly.ClientName;
    finalCollection.MainId = mainOnly.ParsedName;
    //finalCollection.WavName = Convert.ToInt64(wav.ParsedName);
    finalCollection.LastWriteTime = mainOnly.CreationTime;
    finalCollection.folder = mainOnly.FolderName;
    mainAll.Add(finalCollection);
}
```

[`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) will  just check if there´s at least one element in your collection satisfying your codition and if so it returns `true`.

If you also need the values of the first element matching the condition you should however use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) as suggested in the comments which will return `null` if no element was found. However you have to ask for its string-representation (if you overrided `ToString`) or any property within `ConAppFolderFileFinder.FinalFile` which has type `string`.

Comment: So in general would Any be preferred over FirstOrDefault?

Comment: See my edit. Depends on if you want to do anything with the instance being found or just want to check *if* there is any.

Comment: Ok, so actually what I had to do what not equal  if(!final...          thx